# Windows handle to portable device

Tags: c++, c, winapi, handle, createfile

Does anybody know to get a file handle ( e.g. via CreateFile() ) to a 'portable device' ?  If that is possible ?
Like what is possible for drive letters (for instance "\\.\c:") and physical drives (for instance "\\.\PhysicalDrive0")

With portable devices I mean smart phones, gps etc that you can connect via USB to the system.  Windows shows a portable device from where you can (for instance) access the internal memory or SD card.

I would like, if possible, to get handles directly to the SD card or other memory inside the 'portable device' so that I can do file reads of the data.

Is that possible and if so how ?

Comment: Many of these Portable Devices are MTP devices, where you don't have direct access to the device's filesystem, but have to go through something like the [Windows Media Device Manager SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff801840(v=vs.85).aspx) or similar.

Comment: @Hasturkun Thanks.  Hmmm ... that's not what I hoped for (but then, is it ever? ;)  From a quick scan I don't think I will get raw access to the device either then, which is what I need as I interpret the file-system (e.g. FAT) myself.

Comment: On the other hand, many removable devices expose access to their file systems using mapped drive letters, so you don't need low-level access to their hardware.  That way you can access their files via normal file I/O routines without caring that they are removable systems.

Comment: Thanks @RemyLebeau.  However in my experience all devices listed under "portable Devices" in Windows Explorer don't have a drive letter.  For instance if I connect my smart phone or gps via USB using W7, they get listed under "portable devices" and when I click them I see (for instance on the smart phone) two "drives" one is the on board (flash) memory and the other one the micro SD card.  Both don't have a drive letter and are also not available via "PhysicalDrive".

Comment: When I connect my family's various smartphones to our Win7 machines, Windows Explorer pops up new drive letters to access the contents of the smartphones' internal filesystems and SD cards. They are not "physical" drives attached to the Windows machines, obviously, but they do have drive letters assigned to them. Yes, virtual drives on external devices can have drive letters assigned to them. It really depends on the particular drivers used for those devices. Not all manufacturers expose their devices to Windows that way, but some do.

Comment: Let's assume for a second that I gave you the handle. For the sake of the argument, let's call it `\\.\SmartPhone1`. What would you do with it?

Comment: @RemyLebeau.  I see.  Well, my Samsung s3 is not exposed that way, my older Nokia (regular) phone neither, nor my gps.  So indeed it depends on the device and particularly with what drivers it comes.  That also means that a lot of people 'out there' don't have direct access to the drives with my software.

Comment: @MSalters.  I would do file IO with it.  Read data and interpret the data, parse the FAT file-system and have access to the files on the device.

Comment: @Peter: For that, you need more than just a name, you need a physical drive object. Without getting into too many details, [check my patent](http://www.google.com/patents/WO2011026660A1?cl=en) in this area. Even in the best case, when it _looks_ like a FAT file system, it might not be one. And with MTP or ActiveSync you simply can't tell what the filesystem is.

Comment: @MSalters.  It doesn't have to be FAT for me, but if it's something else faking FAT (for instance) then that is not really what I want either.  I'd like access to the raw data, the REAL data. To be able to do data recovery for instance.  Worst case I don't even need a file-system.

Comment: @Peter: On a device like I patented, that wouldn't be effective at all.  Same for MTP. An MTP device may convert its raw images to JPEG on the fly. What exactly did you think you could recover there? You never see the raw images on its internal disk. And trying to "recover" an internal filesystem which you don't understand, by reformatting it to FAT would destroy many devices.

Comment: @MSalters.  I would never write (hence possibly destroy) the image but I was hoping to get direct and raw access to the media.  In many cases that includes removable SD cards which are FAT formatted.  Of course the latter can be removed and put in a card reader and then there is no issue at all.  But I suppose I naively thought or hoped that the internal flash memory would be managed in a similar way, to keep things easy for the device.  for instance the many jpgs stored on my samsung's internal flash memory.

Comment: I have little knowledge of such devices but things are starting to get clearer. I just read about MTP ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_Transfer_Protocol ).  I did, for instance, not think of DRM at all and I understand why MTP might be used in that case.  Still ... it would have been nice to have direct access to the internal flash media to read it and possibly find jpgs etc. in there :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments to my question, the answer to my question is NO.  You can't get a handle to the portable devices.  At least not how and for what I want it.

Unless the driver(s) expose the internal memory and/or drive(s) via drive letter(s), but even then you can't be sure that you get true raw access to the device, since the drivers might be faking the data to make one file system look like another.